# Combine gtk3 in C with gtkmm in C++

Tags: gtk3, gtkmm

I was looking at converting an existing project slowly from C written in gtk3 to C++. Originally, I started to build up classes and was using `extern "C"` to move one function over at a time. However, gtk has it's whole GObject system with special things to instantiate and dispose. (With tons of magic macros created on the fly.)

I started to make a wrapper for Gtk in C++ but it occurs to me that gtkmm already exists for that. Can gtk code be combined with gtkmm? Will signals and slots work across the two, and will it play nicely with the c++ gtkmm objects and c gtk "objects"?

Worst case is I could mirror the objects and cast them back and forth... And handle the creation and deletion in C with gtk so it doesn't break anything, but eventually I want to pull them out of C completely and I think that last bit will be a pain.

Answer (score 0):

All Gtkmm widgets have a method named gobj() to give you the C pointer of your widget so you can call your C functions on it.
https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/stable/sec-basics-gobj-and-wrap.html.en
https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/stable/classGtk_1_1Widget.html

I guess gtk C callbacks are compatible with the gtkmm callbacks:
https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/stable/sec-connecting-signal-handlers.html.en